# col- breaking our of wrapping

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a grasp on how the responsive layout works, so I have taken the responsive col layout from bootstrap.

What I am trying to do is create a red box that fills the space of 1 column and have it sit inside container_fluid>container>row. The moment I add "col-lg-12" into the class it breaks-out of the container_fluid>container>row.

html

```
<div class="container_fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-1 ">
        <div class="red_box"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

css

```
.container_fluid{
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
background-color: #000000;
}
.container{
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
background-color: #367AD7;
}
.row{
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
}
```

The section containing all the col-lg col-md etc is all in the css as well.

Comment: You don't have a closing tag on div.container-fluid

Comment: whoops, sorry when I copy pasted I missed the last closing tag. I was actually already there. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1 ">
        <div class="red_box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

remove the container-fluid div.
I hope it does the work.

Answer (score 0):

The expecting way to use Bootstrap grid system is like this for a fluid container :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1">
      <div class="red_box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And like this for a fixed centered container :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="red_box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In most of cases, you don't need to reset containers and rows margins, it works well with it !

Have a look on the following [example](https://www.bootply.com/mD2SeyzBi9).